# SQL SELECT all datasets where none of them match a criteria

Tags: sql, select, logparser

I wonder if I can request following criteria from a Log Parser database.
(Yes, it's shitty to not have two databases for this but that's what it is.)

Scheme:

```
+-------------------------------------+
|  RegKey   |  Hostname | WinVersion  |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|  Regkey1  |   PC1     |    1909     |
|  Regkey2  |   PC1     |    1909     |
|  Regkey3  |   PC1     |    1909     |
|  Regkey1  |   PC2     |    1803     |
|  Regkey1  |   PC3     |    1909     |
|  Regkey2  |   PC3     |    1909     |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Hostname and WinVersion do fit together in each dataset but each regkey has it's own dataset.
What I'm looking for is a statement to list or count for example *ALL Hostnames WHERE NONE of all datasets HAS (RegKey LIKE RegKey3)*.
So that it results in a list of all Hostnames where RegKey3 is missing.

When I use WHERE and GROUP BY, of course I get all Hostnames because only the RegKey3 datasets are filtered. But is this even possible?
I tried with HAVING but this seems to be only valid with counting or number comparison.

Thanks!

Nico

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
select hostname
from t
group by hostname
having sum(case when RegKey LIKE RegKey3 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

You can try this alternative:

```
select distinct hostname
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.hostname = t.hostname and t2.RegKey like RegKey3);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, wow that was really fast, thank you very much! Unfortunately Log Parser seems to not support this combination of "having": _Error parsing query: Syntax Error: < having-clause >: not a valid < expresion >_

Comment: Actually, LogParser _does_ support HAVING - probably it doesn't support that form of the CASE statement. Can you provide the exact error you get?

Comment: @GabrieleGiuseppini . . . logparser supports both `case` and `having`, so it is odd that this is not supported.  I added another possible method.

Comment: Yes Logparser does support "having" and "case" but I also had other cases where "case" was supported very limited. Even with "-q:OFF" param I get only _Error: Syntax Error: <having-clause>: not a valid <expression>_

Uhm in the second example, do I have to replace "t" in the second select statement?
`select distinct hostname
from '[LOGFILEPATH]'
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.hostname = t.hostname and t2.RegKey like 'PromptOnSecureDesktop')`
_Error: Syntax Error: <term2>: NOT operator not followed by a <term2>_

Comment: `t` is the name of your table.